# Recommendations for taskbar

Tags: unity, taskbar, window-management

I recently updated to Ubuntu 13.10 and now tint2 stopped working. Better yet: it works, I just can not see it as the all bar is now transparent.

Since Tint2 is no longer maintained I doubt it will be updated hence I'm now looking into alternative is there are any.

In short: looking for a  simple taskbar that sits at the bottom of the screen and that lists applications per window (no groupping!). Don't need fancy animations or widgets/features.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "lxpanel", this is a super lightweight no-nonsense taskbar which is fully customizable.

To install lxpanel:

```
sudo apt-get install lxpanel
```

If you decide that you also want the applets for things like network etc.:

```
sudo apt-get install lxpanel-indicator-applet-plugin
```

Comment: Nice suggestion. The lxpanel works quite well! My only problem is that it doesn't group by monitor but that was asking too much already.